# Positive Definite Matrix and Energy

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Why is the expression $x^tSx$ an expression of energy where S is a positive definite matrix?
Ive gotten this from gilbert strangs linear algebra text. the context would be possibly the energy state in a physics problem. I did physics in undergrad and never saw energy expressed like that. Page 4 on this link also repeats this. math.utah.edu/~zwick/Classes/Fall2012_2270/Lectures/… –

Any help appreatiated. thanks in advanced!!:~)

Comment: I'm not following this question. Could you clarify in what context you're referring to? Perhaps it's just a definition?

Comment: Hey Albert, Ive gotten this from gilbert strangs linear algebra text.  the context would be possibly the energy state in a physics problem. I did physics in undergrad and never saw energy expressed like that. Page 4 on this link also repeats this. https://www.math.utah.edu/~zwick/Classes/Fall2012_2270/Lectures/Lecture33.pdf